# How would I remove the brackets and apostrophise from a tuple?

Tags: database, list, sqlite, menu, tuples

I'm trying to create a menu select screen that displays a number and then an item from an sqlite3 database table. The problem I'm having is trying to get rid of the (' parts of the end results to make the menu much tidier.

This is my current code:

```
def product_categories():
    product_categories_query = "SELECT Category_description \
                                FROM Categories \
                                ORDER BY Category_description"
    cursor.execute(product_categories_query)
    product_categories_rows = cursor.fetchall()

    print(f"[1] {product_categories_rows[0]}")
    print(f"[2] {product_categories_rows[1]}")
    print(f"[3] {product_categories_rows[2]}")
    print(f"[4] {product_categories_rows[3]}")
    print(f"[5] {product_categories_rows[4]}")
    print(f"[6] {product_categories_rows[5]}")
```

and this is the result I get:

```
[1] ('Audio and Hifi',)
[2] ('Cameras and accessories',)
[3] ('Computers and accessories',)
[4] ('Gaming',)
[5] ('Mobile phones and accessories',)
[6] ('TV and Home Cinema',)
```

Comment: trim() on `'` and `,` ?

Comment: Is this python code?